# How to specify a file path in handler tag in web.config

Tags: node.js, azure, iis, path, web-config

I am trying to run a simple node.js application on Azure cloud.

I basically followed the instruction written in the following websites.

-Creation of Web application-
 https://code.visualstudio.com/tutorials/app-service-extension/create-app

-Deployment of Web application-
  https://code.visualstudio.com/tutorials/app-service-extension/deploy-app

In order to run it on Azure(IIS), I added web.config and server.js in the root folder as below.
[added 2 files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAyrV.png)

The contents of the files are as follows. 
[web.config]

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
      <handlers>

        <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
        <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
      </handlers>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>

          <!-- All URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->          
          <rule name="DynamicContent">
            <match url="/*" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
          </rule>

        </rules>
      </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

[server.js]
The below shows only a part of the codes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('./app');
var debug = require('debug')('myexpressapp:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */
```

After deployed to Azure(IIS), the web application successfully ran. However, I would like to use the bin/www file instead of server.js. Actually, I created the server.js file in the root folder by coping the bin/www file.
In order to directly use bin/www, I changed the web.config as follows, but this leads to an error. The browser shows the error;"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." It seems that it cannot find the www file. Am I wrong with how I write the path?

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
      <handlers>

        <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
        <add name="iisnode" path="bin/www" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
      </handlers>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>

          <!-- All URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->          
          <rule name="DynamicContent">
            <match url="/*" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="bin/www"/>
          </rule>

        </rules>
      </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

---

I would appriciate any help.

Comment: "The root folder"? Which one? And usually you cannot, as the rules are executed from your site folder, and "bin/www" must be under your site folder. If you want a server level change, you have to use "applicationHost.xdt".

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am sorry for the confusion. It is actually "wwwroot" folder which I meant as "root".                                             web.config exists in this wwwroot folder. In the web.config file, I was trying to refer to the wwwroot/bin/www file, but this cannot be done basically? If I want to write a file path in web.config, the referred files must be in the same folder as web.config?

Comment: Windows uses "\" instead of "/", so I assume you should use "bin\www" instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried that, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem.
I changed the name of the folder from "bin" to some other name and it worked. I am trying to understand why the name "bin" does not work though...Is it because "bin" is kind of reserved by server and it can not be used? I would appriciate it if someone could let me know any possible reasons...